# How can I create an IAM policy on AWS Secrets Manager to grant a group least privilege access. I only grant access to secrets created or owned. Thnx(:

Tags: permissions, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, aws-iam-policy, least-privilege

How can I create an IAM policy on AWS Secrets Manager to only give a group/role least privilege access. I want them to only access the secrets they created and own and not any other secrets. Thank you for your help or guidance in advance !

I have been looking online but didn't find much associated with just least privilege access to only allow secrets owned and created by a group. If you know any good resources I would love to look at it as well